# Count for the selected lines in eclipse editor

Tags: eclipse

How to get count for the selected line at the bottom of the editor in Eclipse IDE?

I want to know how many lines I have selected in editor which would help in counting number of parameters defined in class.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `AbstractTextEditor.getCursorPosition()`.  It gets the line number from the source viewier, caret, and document.

```
 StyledText styledText= fSourceViewer.getTextWidget();
 int caret= widgetOffset2ModelOffset(fSourceViewer, styledText.getCaretOffset());
 IDocument document= fSourceViewer.getDocument();
 int line= document.getLineOfOffset(caret);
```